# What is the appropriate tag to scrape those particular informations?

Tags: python-3.x, tags, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape a bunch of informations from this [website](http://www.zooplus.co.uk/shop/dogs/dry_dog_food/royal_canin_vet_diet).

I need to get product by product a list looking like :

[Name, Packaging, Price/kg]

So for the first one my output would be three lists looking like.

- [Royal Canin Veterinary Diet - Hypoallergenic DR 21, 7kg,4,84]
- [Royal Canin Veterinary Diet - Hypoallergenic DR 21, 14kg,3,71]
- [Royal Canin Veterinary Diet - Hypoallergenic DR 21, 14kg,3,71]

I've managed to get names in a name list.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import urllib.request
from collections import *
import time
start_time = time.clock()

page_0=urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.zooplus.co.uk/shop/dogs/dry_dog_food/royal_canin_vet_diet")
soup_0 = BeautifulSoup(page_0.read(),"html.parser")
restricted_webpage=soup_0.find_all( "tbody", {"class":"product-variants-list"} )
readable_restricted_webpage=str(restricted_webpage)
soup_1 = BeautifulSoup(readable_restricted_webpage,"html.parser")

title=soup_1.find_all("tr", {"style":["background-color:#ffffff;", "background-color:#ededed;"]})

soup_title = BeautifulSoup(str(title),"html.parser")
name=[]



for b in soup_title.find_all("b"):
   name.append(str(b).replace("<b>","").replace("</b>",""))
```

The two others informations are hard to get for me. 
I can't see the tag, the couple of tag i could use to get the (package, price/kg) couple.

I've try with multiple tags and the closest i've got was with : `("td", {"style":"background-color:#ededed;"},{"valign":"top"} )` but i think i should use the `<span>`a way or another ?

How would you proceed guys ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2

url = 'http://www.zooplus.co.uk/shop/dogs/dry_dog_food/royal_canin_vet_diet'
response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
html = response.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")

product_list = soup.find_all("tbody", {"class":"product-variants-list"})

i=0

def visible(text):
    lines = (line.strip() for line in text.splitlines())
    # break multi-headlines into a line each
    chunks = (phrase.strip() for line in lines for phrase in line.split("  "))
    # drop blank lines
    text = ''.join(chunk for chunk in chunks if chunk)
    return text

for product in product_list:

    product_name = product.find("a",{"class":"follow3"}).find("b").text
    print i, product_name
    product_variants = product.find_all("tr",{"class":"product-variant"})

    i +=1



    for variant in product_variants:
        product_weight = variant.find_all("td")[0].string
        print '-'+product_weight,
        print ' | ',
        if variant.find_all("td")[1].find("span",{"class":"specialPrices"}) is not None:
            product_price = variant.find_all("td")[1].find("span",{"class":"specialPrices"}).find("span",{"class":"smalltextPrices"}).get_text(" ", strip=True)
            product_price_per_kg = visible(product_price)
        else:
            product_price = variant.find_all("td")[1].find("span",{"class":"smalltext"}).get_text(" ", strip=True)
            product_price_per_kg = visible(product_price)

        print product_price_per_kg
```

Output:

```html
0 Royal Canin Veterinary Diet - Hypoallergenic DR 21
-- 7kg  |  (£4.84/ kg)
-- 14kg  |  (£3.71/ kg)
-- Economy Pack: 2 x 14kg  |  (£3.68/ kg)
1 Royal Canin Veterinary Diet - Sensitivity Control SC 21
-- 7kg  |  (£5.13/ kg)
-- 14kg  |  (£3.78/ kg)
-- Economy Pack: 2 x 14kg  |  (£3.71/ kg)
2 Royal Canin Veterinary Diet - Gastro Intestinal GI 25
-- 2kg  |  (£6.95/ kg)
-- 7.5kg  |  (£5.05/ kg)
-- 14kg  |  (£3.56/ kg)
-- Economy Pack: 2 x 14kg  |  (£3.50/ kg)
3 Royal Canin Veterinary Diet - Renal RF 14
-- 7kg  |  (£4.99/ kg)
-- 14kg  |  (£3.49/ kg)
-- Economy Pack: 2 x 14kg  |  (£3.43/ kg)
4 Royal Canin Veterinary Diet - Obesity Management DP 34
-- 6kg  |  (£4.82/ kg)
-- 14kg  |  (£3.56/ kg)
-- Economy Pack: 2 x 14kg  |  (£3.50/ kg)
5 Royal Canin Veterinary Diet - Urinary S/O LP 18
-- 7.5kg  |  (£5.05/ kg)
-- 14kg  |  (£3.56/ kg)
-- Economy Pack: 2 x 14kg  |  (£3.50/ kg)
6 Royal Canin Veterinary Diet - Mobility MS 25
-- 7kg  |  (£4.99/ kg)
-- 14kg  |  (£4.06/ kg)
-- Economy Pack: 2 x 14kg  |  (£3.93/ kg)
7 Royal Canin Veterinary Diet - Satiety Support SAT 30
-- 12kg  |  (£3.99/ kg)
-- Economy Pack: 2 x 12kg  |  (£3.91/ kg)
8 Royal Canin Veterinary Diet - Hepatic HF 16
-- 6kg  |  (£5.32/ kg)
-- 12kg  |  (£3.99/ kg)
-- Economy Pack: 2 x 12kg  |  (£3.91/ kg)
9 Royal Canin Veterinary Diet - Dental DLK 22
-- 14kg  |  (£4.14/ kg)
-- Economy Pack: 2 x 14kg  |  (£4.07/ kg)
10 Royal Canin Veterinary Diet - Diabetic DS 37
-- 7kg  |  (£4.99/ kg)
-- 12kg  |  (£3.91/ kg)
-- Economy Pack: 2 x 12kg  |  (£3.75/ kg)
11 Royal Canin Veterinary Diet - Calm CD 25
-- 4kg  |  (£6.72/ kg)
-- Economy Pack: 2 x 4kg  |  (£6.61/ kg)
```